# What is the proper way to implement RetryOperations on XdbUnavailableException?

Tags: xconnect

According to the documentation, you can retry operations by registering them to the client again. I'm doing this on Sitecore 9.0.2.

https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/sitecore-experience-platform/en/handling-exceptions.html

> In the following example, an operation is retried after xConnect returned a 
>   XdbUnavailableException, indicating that the xConnect service was
>   unavailable:
>
> ```
> catch (XdbUnavailableException ex) {
>     // Get any operations that failed
>     var operations = ex.GetOperations(client)
>         .Where(x => x.Status == XdbOperationStatus.Failed);
>
>     foreach (var ops in operations)
>     {
>         client.RegisterOperation(ops);
>     }
>
>     client.SubmitAsync();
> }
> ```

Unfortunately, the code example on the documentation does not work. XdbUnavailableException does not contain a `GetOperations` method.

What should be implemented on an XdbUnavailableException?

Answer (score 1):

Good catch. Documentation indeed is misleading. You should use `XdbExecutionException` which has information about failed operations, hence you can use the client to retry them.

```
catch (XdbExecutionException ex) {
    // Get any operations that failed
    var operations = ex.GetOperations(client)
        .Where(x => x.Status == XdbOperationStatus.Failed);

    foreach (var ops in operations)
    {
        client.RegisterOperation(ops);
    }

    client.SubmitAsync();
}
//catch all other exceptions and retry
catch (Exception)
{
    client.DirectOperations
        .Where(o => o.Status == XdbOperationStatus.Failed)
        .ForEach(op => client.RegisterOperation(op));

    client.SubmitAsync();
}
```

Comment: So when an XdbUnavailableException occurs, there is no way to retry the operations?

Comment: @KoenHeye, it should be possible by checking status of each operation executed by xConnect client. I have updated the answer.